# did the Garfield Kart 2013 online mode ever leave Beta?

Tags: steam, pc

I have seen posts about garfield kart 2013 (not furious racing) having a steam online beta mode.  Did it ever leave beta.  Also, does it support LAN multiplayer?  thnx =)

Comment: anyone know why I got a downvote?  The question seemed clear to me, and I don't think it breaks any of the rules...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following a quick search, the Discussion Board on the Steam page reveals that [Multiplayer is only available in Beta Version](https://steamcommunity.com/app/362930/discussions/0/2961642185092866611/), available from the game's 'Properties' menu in your Steam Library once you have bought it.

This Multiplayer is, apparently, available in both 'local' and 'online' play.

Comment: I saw that, but it was from 2018, so i thought the multiplayer may have moved out of beta by now.  The question is whether by local they mean LAN or splitscreen, and he was using a pirated version, so there is that.  thnx for the answer.  =)

Comment: @Millard The post I linked to was, quite literally, from 5 days ago (18th November 2020)

Comment: oh, I'm sorry,  I thought it was the same post I had read earlier, and I got mixed up between the app number and the question number.  Thanks!  that's helpful.  I wonder why it's not moved out of beta yet, it's been in beta for 2 years.

Comment: but does local mean splitscreen or LAN :|

Comment: @Millard I suspect that they decided it had too many issues to finish completely, but decided not to close the beta

Comment: yeah, and also they released the sequel, which many complain is almost exactly the same as the original, but with 4 more tracks and multiplayer support.  Guess they decided finishing the old multiplayer support wasn't worth it.  better than closing the beta though.  thnx